# Picasso at the art school

Tags: mathematics, probability

Picasso is preparing for his fine art exam. At the exam he will be shown exactly (a replica of) one of the following four [paintings](https://edition.cnn.com/style/article/most-famous-paintings/index.html) chosen uniformly at random:

1. Mona Lisa
2. The Last Supper
3. The Starry Night
4. The Scream.

He is given the challenge to recognize which painting it is out of the above four, and submit his answer in an answer sheet which contains exactly the above four possibilities:
(A) Mona Lisa (B) The Last Supper (C) The Starry Night (D) The Scream. He has to mark exactly one of the four answers (A), (B), (C), or (D). He will pass the exam, if his answer is correct, and would fail otherwise.

Unfortunately, Picasso is very busy painting Guernica, so he has no time to properly prepare for this exam. At the last minute, he were able to learn the painting Mona Lisa only, and while he is confident that he will be able to recognize it during the exam, he has no clue whatsoever about the remaining three pictures.

Assuming that he is doing his very best at the exam, what is the probability of passing?

Comment: Can he recognize if a painting is NOT Mona Lisa? Intuitively, I'd say he would, but since this is tagged mathematics, the wording doesn't mention he is able to recognize "not Mona Lisa". (i.e., the question mentions he can confidently say "this is Mona Lisa" when given a painting of Mona Lisa, but is he also confident that when he is presented the other three painting he can confidently say "this is not Mona Lisa, must be one of the other three")

Comment: I have voted to close this question because as being a mathematical problem because it is solved with a straightforward application of the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability), and there does not seem to be any real surprise puzzling aspect in either the result or the solution method.